# How to know if User pressed the earphone button in JavaScript just like in keydown

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-handling, speech-recognition

I am making an app which start recording when user clicked button on their earphone but I am not able to get the event when user pressed the earphone button using keydown.

JavaScript code that helps to get the even when user clicked the button of their earphone.

Comment: Please make answer it by making function that console logs play when pressed earphone button

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.